# Configure Cloudformation to have requests to GET /subdirectory serve /subdirectory/index.html using Cloudfront & S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sam

I have a Cloudformation template that sets up a AWS::CloudFront::Distribution & AWS::S3::Bucket. Unfortunately, requests to GET /subdirectory respond with a 403. How can I configure the Cloudformation template to have GET /subdirectory serve /subdirectory/index.html?

My Cloudfront configuration looks like:

```
  CloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Aliases:
          - !FindInMap [Domain, !Ref Stage, Domain]
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !Ref Cert
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
        CustomErrorResponses:
        - ErrorCode: 403 # not found
          ResponseCode: 404
          ResponsePagePath: !Ref ErrorPagePath
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
          - GET
          - HEAD
          - OPTIONS
          CachedMethods:
          - GET
          - HEAD
          - OPTIONS
          Compress: true
          DefaultTTL: 3600 # in seconds
          ForwardedValues:
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
            QueryString: false
          MaxTTL: 86400 # in seconds
          MinTTL: 60 # in seconds
          TargetOriginId: s3origin
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        DefaultRootObject: !Ref DefaultRootObject
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: http2
        Origins:
        - DomainName: !GetAtt 'S3Bucket.DomainName'
          Id: s3origin
          S3OriginConfig:
            OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity}'
        PriceClass: 'PriceClass_All'
```

Everything works except requests to GET /subdirectory.

I also tried:

```
        - DomainName: !GetAtt 'S3Bucket.RegionalDomainName'
          Id: s3origin
          S3OriginConfig:
            OriginProtocolPolicy: http-only
```

However I received the error `Property TemplateURL cannot be empty.` on the `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`.

Comment: It looks like I would need to set up a Lambda@Edge function to to the rewrite rule. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/

I'm not yet sure how to implement this using Cloudformation but will follow up once I do the research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Please check this docs, you can find an example like:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-content-based-S3-origin-based-on-query)

```
'use strict';

 const querystring = require('querystring');

 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

     /**
      * Reads query string to check if S3 origin should be used, and
      * if true, sets S3 origin properties.
      */

     const params = querystring.parse(request.querystring);

     if (params['useS3Origin']) {
         if (params['useS3Origin'] === 'true') {
             const s3DomainName = 'my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com';

             /* Set S3 origin fields */
             request.origin = {
                 s3: {
                     domainName: s3DomainName,
                     region: '',
                     authMethod: 'none',
                     path: '',
                     customHeaders: {}
                 }
             };
             request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: s3DomainName}];
         }
     }

    callback(null, request);
};
```

You could change this to point correct `path` using the query string from the request.

Check this to set up [CloudFormation, there is an example on how to set up the trigger](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/managing-lambdaedge-and-cloudfront-deployments-by-using-a-ci-cd-pipeline/)

```
Resources:
    CFDistribution:
        Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
        Properties:
          DistributionConfig:
            Enabled: 'true'
            Comment: !Sub '${Stage} - CI/CD for Lambda@Edge'
            Aliases:
              - !FindInMap [AliasMap, !Ref Stage, Alias]
            Origins:
              -
                Id: MyOrigin
                DomainName: aws.amazon.com
                CustomOriginConfig:
                  HTTPPort: 80
                  OriginProtocolPolicy: match-viewer
            DefaultCacheBehavior:
              TargetOriginId: MyOrigin
              LambdaFunctionAssociations:
                - 
                  EventType: origin-request
                  LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref LambdaEdgeFunctionSample.Version
```